# Determine if task has completed using Delphi

Tags: delphi, pdf, clipboard, shellexecute

I am using the attached code to copy pdf file content into the richedit component.

I don't know how to determine when Acrobat Reader has opened file /copied content, so I use sleep command, which is very inefficient. Later I will need to run this code on thousands of pdf files with different sizes.

Could you please help me to substitute sleep command with the command which will notify when task has completed?

```
var
  Title: array[0..255] of char;
begin
  GetWindowText(wHandle, Title, 255);
  if IsWindowVisible(wHandle) then
  if pos('Adobe Reader',string(Title))>0 then
  begin
    keybd_event(VK_CONTROL,0,0 , 0);
    keybd_event(ord('A'),0,0 , 0);
    keybd_event(ord('A'),0,KEYEVENTF_KEYUP,0);
    keybd_event(VK_CONTROL,0, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP,0);

    keybd_event(VK_CONTROL,0,0 , 0);
    keybd_event(ord('C'),0,0 , 0);
    keybd_event(ord('C'),0,KEYEVENTF_KEYUP,0);
    keybd_event(VK_CONTROL,0, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP,0);
end;
  Result := True;
end;


procedure TForm5.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
    ShellExecute(self.WindowHandle,'open',PChar('D:\Orators.pdf'),nil,nil, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
    sleep(1000);
    EnumWindows(@PDF_to_Clipboard,LPARAM(ListBox1));
    sleep(1000);

    RichEdit1.Lines.Clear;
    RichEdit1.PasteFromClipboard;
end;
```

Comment: What you have is honestly the best you're going to get. Applications have no definitive way to know when they've finished doing some arbitrary thing. Some applications provide a programatic way to interact with them, or even signal with a message or synchronization object when they're *"ready"*; but Acrobat is not one of them. If the goal is to scrape contents of a PDF, you would do better to use a library that can open and let you read the PDF directly - but that's not your question, nor is it an answer to your question.

Comment: Your real problem is that you've chosen a solution that doesn't solve your problem. Use a library that can read PDF files, and extract the content that way.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [AddClipboardFormatListener()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-addclipboardformatlistener) function to be notified when new data is available in the clipboard. You will find a Delphi example [here](http://delphidabbler.com/articles?article=9).

Be aware though that you may receive a notification for every available format (plain text, rich text...).